# Was there a religious revival in Uganda in the late 1980s and 1990s with pervasive impacts on society and the presidency?

Tags: political-history, christianity, africa, religious-history

I recently asked [a related question](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/48611/did-ugandas-president-yoweri-museveni-hand-the-national-flag-to-intercessors-in) on Skeptics.SE, but I haven't received answers (probably because history is not an area of expertise over there). But here I'm interested in the broader context: is it true that there was a Christian religious revival in Uganda in the late 1980s and 1990s with significant positive impacts on society, to the point that even the president [Yoweri Musevini](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yoweri_Museveni) got interested in the religious movement and took part in some of their organized events?

Several religious sites claim such a revival to have occurred (e.g. [1](https://worldtrumpet.wixsite.com/world-trumpet/uganda-story), [2](https://www1.cbn.com/700club/jackson-senyonga-uganda-revival), [3](https://www.luziusschneider.com/News/English/UgandaE.htm), [4](https://www.charismamag.com/site-archives/146-covers/cover-story/1965-ugandas-miracle)), but these sites are far from being reliable, unbiased sources.

Examples of the alleged benefits of the revival claimed by these sites are:

> 1990. World Trumpet Mission was birthed as a ministry. WTM actions a call to nationwide prayer & repentance in pursuit of destiny. **HIV/AIDs drop 34% to 6%, Church influences all areas of society. Nations around the world hear of transformation taking place in Uganda** *[worldtrumpet](https://worldtrumpet.wixsite.com/world-trumpet/uganda-story)(emphasis mine)*

> In the early 1990s a prophetic word came through Israeli believers that said Uganda would be the breadbasket to the world in the end time harvest. 
>  
> Jackson says they are seeing **changes with people at the highest levels of the government being concerned with moral standards and enforcing principles of God's Word**. New government ministries have been established, including the Ministry of Ethics and Integrity. **Christians are being placed in the most sensitive positions**. Laws are being rewritten to favor God's principles and Word. Members of parliament are meeting weekly for prayer. Judges acknowledge praying privately. Police often send prayer requests to churches. **First lady Museveni prays publicly and encourages all sectors of his government to hold morning and lunch-time prayer meetings**. Every day from 5:00 to 6:00 a.m. and again from 11:00 p.m. to midnight live intercessory prayer is broadcast across the nation on radio. [...] **The crime rate has dropped 50 percent**.  *[CBN](https://www1.cbn.com/700club/jackson-senyonga-uganda-revival)(emphasis mine)*

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/East_African_Revival) there was an East African Revival in the 1930s and 1940s having Uganda among the reached countries, but the article says nothing about the late 1980s and 1990s.

The closest to a reliable source that might give a little credence to the claim is the [Personal life](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yoweri_Museveni#Personal_life) section of the Wikipedia article on Yoweri Museveni, which states that:

> Museveni is an Evangelical Christian and has preached a few times at the Miracle Centre Cathedral, a church he inaugurated in 2004.

However, this still does not tell us anything about his alleged involvement in any religious revival in the 1990s.

Was there really a religious revival in Uganda in the late 1980s and 1990s with widespread effects on society and the presidency as claimed by some religious sites?

Comment: Welcome to History:Stack Exchange. Thank you for your question; please consider revising it to be more in line with our community expectations. Like many other stacks, we expect questions to [provide evidence of prior research](https://interpersonal.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3227/1599). That helps us to understand the question, and avoids our repeating work you've already done. Our [help], and [other stacks](https://interpersonal.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3224/how-do-i-write-a-good-question) provide additional resources to assist with revisions.

Comment: There are certainly [claims](https://www.independent.co.uk/news/world/africa/how-uganda-was-seduced-anti-gay-conservative-evangelicals-9193593.html) that American conservative evangelical groups have been active in Uganda since the fall of Idi Amin in 1979.

Comment: What kind of positive effects are you talking about?

Comment: @NeMo I just added a couple of examples

Comment: I suggest you keep it to what is scientifically provable. Assertions like 'people with aids were supernaturally healed' really have my finger itching for the down arrow. I haven't downvoted as you're a newbie to the History stack, but unless you make an effort to clean it up, someone will soon close it.

Comment: @NeMo thanks for the warning, I replaced that sentence with [...]

Comment: Lots of information online about the rise of American Evangelicism in the country since 1979, including many Evangelical NGOs. The Joshua Project reports that the country is 90% Christian (33% Evangelical). Nothing specific about how this rise of Evangelicism came about, however. The large number of Evangelical NGOs could have something to do with that, but again, no definitive source that I could find. This same growth is happening in many countries in Africa. It appears to be coupled with a rise in homophobia as well.

Comment: I don't have time to put together an answer (not least because the answer is complicated), but you will find this Journal of African Studies and Development article, [State regulation of religion in Uganda: Fears and
dilemmas of born-again churches](https://academicjournals.org/journal/JASD/article-full-text-pdf/222D4B962201) to be of some use.

Comment: One can certainly expect that 10 or 20 years after Idi Amin was gone, some improvement must be visible - including in the spiritual well being of the society.  In dictatorships people live lies, in a larger degree than the usual government lies.. More freedom, even if still partial,  must have helped. I remember also scattered info about Musevini sometimes protecting Uganda from progressive NGOs and UN pushes to e.g. abortion. Maybe it isn't a miracle, just comparing a normal situation with a abnormally bad one. If nobody is screwing the country too bad, it should go forward.

Comment: @LarsBosteen it looks like the article does give some credence to the claim that there was a rapid proliferation of so called "born-again" believers throughout Uganda during Yoweri Musevini's administration. The article you shared also says that Musevini was initially neutral regarding his religious position. However, [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yoweri_Museveni#Personal_life) says Musevini inaugurated his own evangelical church in 2004. Does this mean he converted during the process? Does this give credence to the claim that the religious revival reached the presidency too?

Comment: @SpiritRealmInvestigator Depends what you mean by 'reached the presidency'. Did Musevini and his wife exploit it (and were they to some extent exploited by it)? Certainly, but belief may be another matter...

Comment: "profound positive impacts"...This is at best opinion-based and possibly a push question.

Comment: @Spencer: fixed.

Comment: *probably because history is not an area of expertise over there* - Or, more probably, because there aren't many Ugandans on that particular site; or on this one, for that matter, which would also help explain the equal lack of any answers here as well.